# how to change my display name as amazon mturk requester?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to change my display name as a requester in mturk. Instead of my real name, I want a company name to show up.

Whatever I tried, did not make this change.

I tried changing my name in "Account Settings" in mturk, my global Amazon name, my Amazon address, nothing helped.

Also, I get inconsistent behavior with respect to what's shown in the greeting when I log-in to mturk. Sometimes the company name is shown, and sometimes my real name is shown (in the same spot).

(for workers, my real name is always displayed.)

I am not the first to have this problem:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=209269

Comment: This should just be your global amazon name, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your name can be done online by following these steps:

1. Log into your Requester account at -- https://requester.mturk.com/
2. Click the "My Account" link in the upper right corner.
3. Under "Personal Settings", click the "Edit" button next to your name.
4. Log into the following screen to confirm ownership of the account.
5. Click the "Edit" button next to your name again.
6. Update your name and click the "Save Changes" button.

The change won't take effect shortly. It took a couple of hours in my experience, and somebody said 48+ hours. Anyway, being patient would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/) and sign in. Click `Your account`, and then under settings, click `Change Account Settings`.

Editing the name there will change the name displayed to workers for `Requester:`.

Source: I just did this and it worked for me.